# Как использовать UserControl в проекте VS2010

Tags: c#, wpf, usercontrol

Подскажите как добавить пользовательский контрол в проект VS 2010. Пробовал контролы из [этой](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35324285/how-to-create-masked-textbox-like-windows-ip-address-fields) ветки Стака и из [репозитория](https://github.com/bingelp/WPF-IPAddress-Cntrl) для VS2012 от неизвестного автора. В редакторе отображаются, но в окно приложения не понятно как добавлять. Варианты использования, что прилагаются к этим решениям не подходят. VS пишет что ссылка на объект задана неправильно.

Ошибка при добавлении следующая:

> Тип "MyProjectName:IPTextBox" не найден. Убедитесь, что не пропущена ссылка
>   на сборку и что все сборки, на которые заданы ссылки, построены.

Контрол располагается в том же пространстве имён `MyProjectName.common.control`.

Comment: В окно добавляйте через `local:IPTextBox`

Comment: Данная строка не зависит от места расположения объекта? Имеется ввиду корень проекта или папка вложения.

Comment: Зависит от пространства имен, в котором расположен контрол. Вы должны объявить пространство имен в XAML и указывать его через двоеточие перед названием контрола.

Comment: Не получается. Та же ошибка. Вопрос обновил.

Comment: Посмотрите как в разметке окна у вас задано пространство имен `local` (должно быть что-то вроде `xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfTest"`), вот вы должны объявить свое пространство имен аналогично. Например: `xmlns:controls="clr-MyProjectName.common.control"`, тогда обращаться к контролу можно будет как `controls:IPTextBox`

Comment: Спасибо. Строка `xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MyProjectName.common.control"` решила проблему.